# CSS: Fixed/pinned top menu bar

Tags: html, css

I read through many questions regarding this on SO, but did not find really what I am looking for. I have the simple HTML and CSS code below. What I am trying to do is to put the scroll bar only on the "left_content" DIV. As you can see in the example now its on the "left" DIV. If I move the "scroll:auto" in the CSS from #left into #left_content, the scroll bar appears on the right. Why is that? and how can I place the scroll bar on the #left_content. Thanks.

```
<style>
  #left{float:left; width:50%; height:100%; overflow:auto;}
  #right{float:left; width:50%; height:100%;}  
  #left_menu{width:100%;}
  #left_content{width:100%;}
  .clear{clear:both;}
</style>
<div id="left">
  <div id="left_menu">
  menu point 1 | menu point 2 | menu point 3
  </div>
  <div id="left_content">
    1 <br / >2 <br / >3 <br / >4 <br / >5 <br / >6 <br / >7 <br / >8 <br / >9 <br / >10 <br / >11 <br / >12 <br / >13 <br / >14 <br / >15 <br / >16 <br / >17 <br / >18 <br / >19 <br / >20 <br / >21 <br / >22 <br / >
    1 <br / >2 <br / >3 <br / >4 <br / >5 <br / >6 <br / >7 <br / >8 <br / >9 <br / >10 <br / >11 <br / >12 <br / >13 <br / >14 <br / >15 <br / >16 <br / >17 <br / >18 <br / >19 <br / >20 <br / >21 <br / >22 <br / >
    1 <br / >2 <br / >3 <br / >4 <br / >5 <br / >6 <br / >7 <br / >8 <br / >9 <br / >10 <br / >11 <br / >12 <br / >13 <br / >14 <br / >15 <br / >16 <br / >17 <br / >18 <br / >19 <br / >20 <br / >21 <br / >22 <br / >
  </div>
</div>
<div id="right">
 Some other content that is adjusted so that there is no scrolling needed.
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>​
```

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/kubqrvrk/

Comment: `<br/>` is deprecated. Use the alternatives

Comment: Thanks. What I'm looking for is no scroll bar anywhere else just on the #left_content.

Comment: That's what my JSFiddle does.

Comment: @Godisgood In the fiddle there are 2 scroll bars, one on the right and one on the left DIV that is encompassing the left_menu DIV. I would like the left_menu DIV to be pinned down and ONLY the left_content DIV to be scrollable.

Comment: Ok.  I'm working on it.

Comment: @Godisgood  Thanks. If it works, post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I will.  Can I use a table?

Comment: If not, I'll need to use JS.

Comment: @Godisgood JS is fine too.

Comment: I should note that having 100% height on everything is worthless unless the parent element has a specified height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason behind the scroll bar appearing on the right instead for the left div only is that you have set height for both left and right as 100%. The scrollbar appearing is not for the right div but for the body/document.

Overflow css works best when you have fixed height. If you still need 100% height, we can include:

```
#left { max-height: 500px;}
```

If you need to set the height of the left div to the window height, its possible using JS.

```
$('#left').css('max-height',$(window).height());
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h4adr4qs/

Or using the new css viewport values:

```
#left {max-height:100vh;}
```

I'm not sure how many browsers support 'vh' units. But i'm pretty sure will become a standard soon.

If you need the menu pinned but only #left_content to scroll, you need to set the max-height to that div,

```
#left_content { max-height: 500px;overflow:scroll}
```

IF you do this, remove overflow property from #left css

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to do is add a specific height to the left div, for example:

```
#left { height: 300px; }
```

Note that you can't use percentages here. Pixels, Ems, or any specific unit will work. Now make the left content take up a part of that, and tell it to scroll:

```
#left_content { 
    height: 90%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

That's pretty much it. Works great in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/kubqrvrk/5/